# how to add edittext when checkbox is checked

Tags: android

i have a bunch of checkboxes, when a checkbox is checked I need to add an edittext field  corresponding to that checkbox, i have tried in a way like the below code, bt its having error in the logcat, thanks in advance  here is my code:

```
 cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                public void onCheckedChanged(android.widget.CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String str="";

                    if(cb.isChecked()) {
                        /*//int tag=(Integer) cb.getTag();
                        final EditText et=new EditText(NewOrder.this);
                        et.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        et.setTextSize(16);
                        et.setPadding(10, 5, 10, 5);
                        //et.setBackgroundDrawable(NewOrder.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.edittext_border));
                        tr.addView(et);
                        // table.addView(tr);

                        //Long tag = (Long) buttonView.getTag();
                        */
                        str=str+cb.getText();
                        adapter3.add(str);
                        //String t= tag.toString();
                        Toast.makeText(NewOrder.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else //(!(cb.isChecked())) {
                        str=str+cb.getText();
                        adapter3.remove(str);
                        // Toast.makeText(NewOrder.this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                });
               }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: U said u have an error in your logcat, so would you please share it with us , i think it will be useful, and remove the try and catch statements

Comment: show your log error, you code is not formated and not visible, there is a catch but no try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to add the EditText to the view on runtime by creating one you can try to add it from the begining and then toggle its visibility like:

```
      if(cb.isChecked())
      {
             // ....
             et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              // ....
       } 
       else //(!(cb.isChecked()))
       {
             // ....
             et.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
             // ....
       }
```

Implement the whole project to use or ignore the EditText visibility.

Comment: checkbox is created dynamically on box checked, bt how to clear it from the view when the checkbox is unchecked? madlymad

Comment: You do not really clear it... you just make it invisible. GONE means that the controller does not take any place in screen. This is a way to avoid handling all `addView` and `removeView` handlings in your layout.